# How to encode/decode video to flash media server using ActionScript

Tags: video, actionscript, decode, encode

I want to encode a video to obtain high quality. Is there any way to encode a video on flash media server?

Comment: Through I not very familiar with scripts and codes, I got a nice tutorial about how to convert video to flash: http://www.kvisoft.com/tutorials/convert-videos-to-flash.html Hope it can help you a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flash Media Server doesn't encode videos, you will need ffmpeg for that. It can be easily installed as a command line on your server then you can use it from PHP or other scripting language.

Comment: Thanks it was quite helpful..!